# Parse XML and save instances of tags in variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have the variable `response`, holding a XML string

```
<tag>
  <innerTag>
    <ex0>1000</ex0>
    <ex1>2000</ex1>
    <ex2>3000</ex2>
  </innterTag>
  <innerTag>
    <ex0>4000</ex0>
    <ex1>7000</ex1>
    <ex2>2500</ex2>
  </innterTag>
</tag>
```

I want to parse the string and adding each tags value to a variable that i can use to further process the data.
I'm using jQuery and so far I got

```
[...]

var response = request.responseXML.documentElement;
$.get(response, {}, function(xml){
  $('innerTag', xml).each(function(){
    ex0 = $(this).find("ex0").text();
    ex1 = $(this).find("ex1").text()
    ex2 = $(this).find("ex2").text()    
  })
})

[...]
```

The most obvious problem is that I have multiple "innerTag"s. How can I assign each value to a variable?
Problem is, that I need to pass all ex0, ex1 and ex2 to another function so it would be wise to name the variables something like inner0_ex0, inner1_ex0 for the different ex0 values and so on.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "further process"? Your `.each()` body runs two times, can't you do your further processing there?

Comment: That's *exactly* my point. Why don't you call that other function in the body of `each()` right-away? What's the point in saving the values?

Comment: because the functions starts a mediaplayer and ex0 - ex? are freezes that the player needs when it starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to store the results into arrays like this:

```
$.get(response, {}, function(xml){
  var ex0 = [];
  var ex1 = [];
  var ex2 = [];
  $('innerTag', xml).each(function(){
    ex0.push($(this).find("ex0").text());
    ex1.push($(this).find("ex1").text());
    ex2.push($(this).find("ex2").text());
  });
  /* Access them here as ex0[0] or ex0[1], etc. */
})
```